# Jmeter assertion is failing despite of same actual and expected values

Tags: groovy, jmeter, assertion, jsr223

Iam tring to compare a String parameter value from my JSON response to another String value stored in a variable. 
As the log shows both expected and Actual variables have same value but the assertion is failing. Where am I doing wrong? please guide

```
String actual =  vars.get("DataSourceFormula").toString();
log.info ("Actual Datasource formula is found to be: " + actual);

String expected="Automation Testing+Automation Testing";
vars.put("expected",expected);
log.info ("Expected Datasource formula should be:" + expected);

if (vars.get("expected") != vars.get("actual")) {
props.put("testcaseExecutionStatus",5);
String Status = props.get("testcaseExecutionStatus").toString();
log.info("Status:"+ Status)
AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Mismatch between expected and actual 
 return;
} 

props.put("testcaseExecutionStatus",1);
String Status = props.get("testcaseExecutionStatus").toString();
log.info("Status:"+ Status)
```

[image]JSON')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's due to some [non-printable character](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-cookbook/0596001703/ch03s12.html) like extra space or line break or character from another locale, for example `a` and `а` are different beasts.

You can try converting the strings to [char arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) and comparing char by char or alternatively you can use a normal [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved/) in order to compare 2 values, it will highlight the mismatches, the relevant configuration would be as simple as:

[image]